# How do i merge rows with same index on a single data frame but other columns adapt values as a string?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, jupyter-notebook

I have tried it this way but it works only for one column but i have to do it with multiple i tried with list but it just throws out column index text not values

```
frame.groupby(['Country'])['Happiness Score'].apply(lambda x:', '.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()
```

I m trying to do it like this

```
frame.groupby(['Country'])['Happiness Score','Happiness Rank', ...].apply(lambda x:', '.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need `set_index` an `stack` followed by a `groupby.agg`:

```
frame.set_index('Country')[['Happiness Score','Happiness Rank', 'more_cols']].stack()\
                          .astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
```

Comment: Seems to be workin fine but headers are gibe other than Country which works fine.

Comment: @TRivan no problem, don't forget to accept the answer.